# Procedure- case statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure such as below:

```
SELECT @AdminApproved = CASE WHEN @AdminApprovalDate IS NULL
    THEN 0 
    ELSE 1
    END
```

As I understand the `CASE` statement, `@AdminApproved` should never be anything other than 0 or 1. There's no way it can possibly be NULL. And yet I am getting NULL !!!! Can Any one help me for the same?

Comment: Weird but if you use `SELECT @AdminApproved = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@AdminApprovalDate,0) = 0
    THEN 0 
    ELSE 1
    END` does it work?

Comment: [The code you've shown](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3222) **can't** return `NULL` so either you've uncovered a bug or you are not showing us everything.

Comment: beware of `set @AdminApprovalDate = ''`

Answer (score 7):

### Your example code works

According to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3218) this works. It's either set to 0 or 1. So if you're using exactly the code you're showing us this variable can't be `null`.

```
declare @AdminApproved1 bit
declare @AdminApproved2 bit
select @AdminApproved1 = case when (null) is null then 0 else 1 end,
       @AdminApproved2 = case when (getdate()) is null then 0 else 1 end

-- both have values
select @AdminApproved1, @AdminApproved2;
```

### But variable can still be `null`

So if your code example isn't complete then [I can show you another example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b7c1/3) where both upper variables would be `null` even after executing `select` statement. And I suspect that your problem is related.

```
declare @AdminApproved1 bit
declare @AdminApproved2 bit
select @AdminApproved1 = CASE WHEN (null) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
       @AdminApproved2 = CASE WHEN (getdate()) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
from SomeTable
where 0 = 1 -- this query yields no results

-- both are NULL when
select @AdminApproved1, @AdminApproved2;
```

Comment: +1 The most likely explanation. I only regret not having thought of that myself :). It does show the perrils of not showing enough detail when asking questions though.

Comment: @Robert: Yes this will be helpful to me. I have taken just those code where there seems riddle to me. Btw thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Mudassir: So was that the problem? Have you been querying against some table with `where` clause that yielded no results? I mean did my answer resolve your problem? If it did, do not forget to accept it (as I can see you're a new user around here).

Comment: Yes the problem was the same as you mentioned.I have used your illustration and got solution of my problem.N Yeah I am new user of the same! Thanks for instant reply ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get null from that query, so there has to be something else that is wrong somewhere else in your code. It's likely that there is something that keeps that query from executing at all.

Test to verify the result:

```
declare @AdminApproved int
declare @AdminApprovalDate datetime

-- testing with null

set @AdminApprovalDate = null

SELECT @AdminApproved = CASE WHEN @AdminApprovalDate IS NULL
    THEN 0 
    ELSE 1
    END

select @AdminApproved

-- testing with a date

set @AdminApprovalDate = getdate()

SELECT @AdminApproved = CASE WHEN @AdminApprovalDate IS NULL
    THEN 0 
    ELSE 1
    END

select @AdminApproved
```

Output:

```
0

1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a value with `SELECT` will *preserve* the original value before the asignment if inside the select no rows are returned. (Actually it is not true, that the value will be `NULL` it will be a preserved value.

Only case of SET is possible that an assignment which returns no row sets the value to `NULL`.

So in your special case, the value previous value was NULL (because you did not assign a value) and your select did not return.